# Android Studio 3.5.3 debugging on Sony Xperia XA2 Ultra

Tags: android-studio, sony-xperia

My Android Studio does not recognize my Xperia XA2 Ultra phone for debugging my app.

I checked that Google USB Driver was installed in the SDK tools of Android Studio.
I tried connecting my phone to my laptop in USB 2.0 and USB 3.0.
But my phone is connected in MTP mode and I can't find any option on the phone to change it to MSC mode.

Comment: Enable Developer options and USB debugging as instructed in [Configure on-device developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) in Android documentation.

Comment: Developer options and USB debugging are enabled on my phone but still it is not recognized by Android Studio.

Comment: What about a driver from Sony? See: [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb)

Comment: Windows says that the best driver for my device is already installed.

Comment: Windows knows nothing about Android development. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Sony Xperia XA2 Dual. Finally I found the solution: switch USB preferences to "No data transfer" or "USB tethering" mode.[image: switched to No data tranfer]

One sad thing is that you won't be able to simultaneously transfer files and debugging apps (but you have the Device Explorer working as usual).